# looping the match method in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to ask if there's any short way to repeat a method for each element of an array. I have to count the number of occurrences of each letter in input box, and my idea was to use `.match(/letter/gi).length` and execute it for each element of this array: `var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");` Is this possible?

Comment: I believe your looking for a for loop

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object to store character as property, number of characters as value; `Object.hasOwnProperty()`, `change` event attached to `input type="text"` element where `for` loop iterates `value` of `input type="text"` element and sets properties, values of created object; `input type="button"` element to display results, reset `input type="text"` element value to empty string `""`.

```js
var input = document.querySelector("input[type=text]")
, button = document.querySelector("input[type=button]")
, output = document.querySelector("pre")
, obj = {};

input.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  var letters = event.target.value;
  for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(letters[i])) {
      obj[letters[i]] = 1; // set initial value to `1`
    } else {
      ++obj[letters[i]] // increment value of `obj[letters[i]]`
    }
  };
});

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log(obj);
  output.textContent = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2); // display result
  input.value = ""; // reset `input` to `""`
})
```

```html
<input type="text" />
<input type="button" value="Count characters" />
<pre>
</pre>
```